# How can parent component reset many children in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am writing an application that consists of a large grid of squares. Each square (or cell) maintains its own state. Clicking on an individual cell changes its colour (the Cell uses useState())

I want to have a single reset button that will set all the cells back to their initial state i.e. coloured white.

I can't work out how to get this single button to change the state of all the cells. The number of cells can vary (depending on the layout size selected) be between 121 and 529 of them.

Any advice greatfully accepted!

Comment: Please provide an example code how you build your grid.

Comment: use props to alter state in children, it will cause re-render if props change

Comment: Each component must be responsible of its own state. If you want to reset the state of each square _from the parent component_, it probably means that the state is owned _by the parent component_ and should be forwarded to your children components through properties. Therefore, your square components will become slave and stateless and only the parent will have a state.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the parent to maintain state for such  large number of children?

Comment: i can't think of an elegant solution off the top of my head, but i would lean towards utilising refs, `react.forwardref` and `useimperativehandle` to expose state/function for setting state from the child components to the parents. or, if you wanna be lazy, you could just toggle a key on the grid itself which would cause the the entire grid cells to be rebuilt from scratch but that would be relatively quite slow ...

Comment: Lift the state up, pass a function to the child component to manipulate the state.
See: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to actually change the key of the common parent of the grid element that forces all the children to remount and this resetting all their states

Sample demo

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
   state = {
      counter: 0
   }
   render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.counter}<button onClick={() => this.setState(prev => ({counter: prev.counter+1}))}>Increment</button></div>
    )
   }
}
class App extends React.Component{
 state = {
  elemKey: 0,
 }
 
 render() {
  return (
   <React.Fragment>
    <div key={this.state.elemKey}>
      {[...Array.from(new Array(10))].map((item, index) => {
         return <Child key={index} />
      })}
    </div>
    <button onClick={() => {this.setState(prev => ({elemKey: (prev.elemKey + 1)%2}))}}>Reset</button>
   </React.Fragment>
  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `context` and wrap all your `cells` in `context.provider` and then in your `cells` `useEffect` hook listen for the result of context if it changed you can change the state of each cell to its initial something like this:

```
//in resetContext.js

const ResetContext = React.createContext();

const useResetContext = () => React.useContext(resetContext);

//in resetContextProvider.js

const ResetContextProvider = () => {
  const [reset, setReset] = React.useState(false);
  const providerValue = {reset, setReset}

  return (
    <ResetContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
      //put your Cells in here
    </ResetContext.Provider>
  )
}

// in Cells

const initialValue = 'something';

const Cell = () => {
  const [cellState, setCellState] = React.useState(initialValue)
  const resetObj = useResetContext();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(reset){
      setCellState(initialValue)
    }
  }, [resetObj])

  return <div /> // or whatever your components are
}
```